# make: cannot find makedepend

Tags: c, makefile

I am trying to run the following makefile

```
CMDLINE_SRC=$(wildcard commandLine/*.c)
CMDLINE_OBJS = $(CMDLINE_SRC:.c=.o)
EXECUTABLES = $(CMDLINE_SRC:.c=)

LIB_SRC=$(wildcard c/*.c)
LIB_OBJ = $(LIB_SRC:.c=.o)
LIB_OUT = lib/libclinrisk.a

INCLUDES = -I include

# compiler
CC = gcc
CCFLAGS = 
LDFLAGS = 

# library paths
LIBS = -Llib -lclinrisk -lm

.SUFFIXES: .c

default: dep executables

executables: $(EXECUTABLES)
    cp $(EXECUTABLES) executables

$(EXECUTABLES): $(LIB_OUT)

.c:
    $(CC) $(INCLUDES) $(LDFLAGS) $< -o $@ $(LIBS)

.c.o:
    $(CC) $(INCLUDES) $(CCFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(LIB_OUT): $(LIB_OBJ)
    ar rcs $(LIB_OUT) $(LIB_OBJ)

depend: dep

dep:
    makedepend -- $(CFLAGS) -- -I /usr/include/linux $(INCLUDES) $(LIB_SRC)

clean:
    rm -f $(LIB_OBJ) $(LIB_OUT) Makefile.bak
    rm -f $(CMDLINE_OBJ) $(CMDLINE_PROGS) 
    rm -f executables/*

# DO NOT DELETE
```

and getting the following error message:

```
$ make
makedepend --  -- -M
make: makedepend: Command not found
make: *** [dep] Error 127
```

i gather that I may not have makedepend install as if I press tab after typing in make I get:

```
$ make <TAB>
clean        default      dep          depend       executables  makefile
```

If it is so that I don't have makedepend installed, how do I install it and point

```
makedepend -- $(CFLAGS) -- -I /usr/include/linux $(INCLUDES) $(LIB_SRC)
```

at what it needs to point at?

thanks!

UPDATE: Davides answer has solved the problem...

however I am now stuck with:

```
$ make
makedepend --  -- -I /usr/include/linux -I include 
cp  executables
cp: missing destination file operand after `executables'
Try `cp --help' for more information.
make: *** [executables] Error 1
```

i suspect this a is a problem with the actual makefile....

Comment: What's your OS? Your question "how do I install [makedepend]" depends on this.

Comment: Don't edit the question to add a new question.  Instead, press the "Ask Question" button at the top of the screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You miss the `makedepend` tool.

Install it by compiling the source (so you're distro-independent) following this instructions:

[Download and install makedepend](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/x/makedepend.html)

Comment: thanks, that solved the problem, however I am getting a new problem, which have edited into my question.

Comment: For ubuntu, package name is xutils-dev